# Bash: Compare alphanumeric string with lower and upper case

Tags: string, bash

Given a directory with files with an alphanumeric name:

```
file45369985.xml
file45793220.xml
file0005461x.xml
```

Also, given a csv table with a list of files

```
file45369985.xml,file,45369985,.xml,https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/id/FILE:45369985/Understanding-terrorism-challenges-perspectives?cHash=16d713678274dd2aa205fc07b2fc5b86
file0005461X.xml,file,0005461X,.xml,https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/id/FILE:0005461X/The-reality-of-social-construction?cHash=5d8152fbbfae77357c1ec6f443f8c8a4
```

I would like to match all files in the csv table with the directory's content and move them somewhere else. However, I cannot switch off the case sensitivity in this command:

```
while read p; do
        data_set=$(echo "$p" | cut -f1 -d",")

        # do something else
done
```

How can the "X-Files" be correctly matched as well?

Comment: Is there anything else in the csv table?

Comment: Indeed, although it is a bit messy. This is the first line:

file886363578.xml,file,886363578,.xml,https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/id/FILE:886363578/Understanding-terrorism-challenges-perspectives?cHash=16d713678274dd2aa205fc07b2fc5b86

Comment: @Yahalnaut, broken link? Also please add a minimal and relevant sample of your csv table directly in the question body.

Comment: You will need to post an exact sample of the csv, properly formatted. It will be difficult to help otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the format of the csv file (no quotes around the first field), I show an answer for filenames without newlines.

List all files in current directory

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Look for one filename in that list (ignoring case)

```
grep -Fix file0005461X.xml <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n")
```

Show first field only from file

```
cut -d"," -f1 csvfile
```

Pretend that the output is a file

```
<(cut -d"," -f1 csvfile)
```

Tell `grep` to use that "file" for strings to look for with option `f`

```
grep -Fixf <(cut -d"," -f1 csvfile) <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n")
```

Move to /tmp

```
grep -Fixf <(cut -d"," -f1 csvfile) <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n") |
  xargs -i{} mv "{}" /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` to perform a inner join between the CSV and the file list:

```
join  -i -t, \
      <(sort -t, -k1 list.csv) \
      <(find given_dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort) \
      -o "2.1"
```

Explanation:

- **`-i`**: perform a case insensitive comparison for the join
- **`-t,`**: use the comma as a field separator
- **`<(sort -t, -k1 list.csv)`**: sort the CSV file on the first field using the comma as a field separator and use the output as a file, and perform a process substitution to "connect the output" to a file and use it as file argument (see [Bash manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash))
- **`<(find given_dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort)`**: list all the file stored in the root of the given directory `given_dir` (and not in the subdirectories), sort it and perform a process substitution like the above
- **`-o "2.1"`**: list the first column of the second input (the `find` output) of the join result

---

***Note:** this solution relies on **GNU** `find` due to `printf` command*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F [,\.] '{ print substr($1,1,length($1)-1)toupper(substr($1,length($1)))"."$2;print substr($1,1,length($1)-1)tolower(substr($1,length($1)))"."$2 }' csvfile | while read line
do
    find /path -name "$line" -exec mv '{}' /newpath \;
done
```

Use awk and set the file delimiter to . and , Take each line and generate both an uppercase and lowercase X version of the file name.

Loop through this output and find the file in a given path. If the file exists, execute the move command to a given path.

Comment: You're moving a file into its root directory, not "somewhere else". Also are you sure the case differs only on "X"? Last and just as a side note this solution invokes `find` for each CSV entry... Maybe there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: path for both root and exec was an oversight. Should just process the Xs and yeah, it probably isn't the most efficient solution but an option none the less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -i` to make case insensitive matches:

```sh
while read p; do
    data_set=$(echo "$p" | cut -f1 -d",")
    match=$(ls $your_dir | grep -i "^$data_set\$")
    if [ ! -z match ]; then
        mv "$match" $another_dir
    fi
done
```